# Issues with assigning URL to an optional URL State variable

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to assign variable "furl" to @State var fileurl: URL? in saveImage() of my MainScreenView(). In saveImage Print(furl) shows the URL, but after assigning fileURL = furl, print(fileurl) returns nil, that's the issue. Removing the optional doesn't allow it to build as:

```
if let furl = fileurl {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: furl)
                if let img = UIImage(data: data) {
                    return img
                }.
```

of loadImage()Throws an error of "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'URL'". I'm unsure what to do in this case.

Here's MainScreenView

```
import SwiftUI
import SafariServices

struct MainScreenView: View {
    
    @State var isfound = true
    @State var failed = false
    @State var ShowInstruction = false
    @State var fileurl: URL? //I'm guessing since this is an optional, it's not allow it to do something correctly?
    @State var ShowBadge = false
    @State var ShowPortal = false
    @State var ShowDetails = false
    @State var alert = false
    @State var listalert = false
    @State var truebadge: Bool = false
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            Color("BackgroundMain")
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .overlay(
                    VStack{
                        Button {
                            ShowBadge = true
                        } label: {
                            if truebadge != true{
                                VStack{
                                    Image(systemName: "person")
                                        .font(.system(size: 120))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                        .padding()
                                    Text("expired compliance")
                                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                }.offset(y: -30)
                            }
                            else {
                                VStack{
                                    Image(systemName: "person")
                                        .font(.system(size: 120))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color("MainBadgeScreen"))
                                        .padding()
                                    Text("Show Complaince")
                                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color("MainBadgeScreen"))
                                }.offset(y: -30)
                            }
                        }
                        Button  {
                            
                        } label: {
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "lanyardcard")
                                Text("Student ID")
                            }
                            .font(.system(size: 23))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 65, alignment: .center)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                            .offset(y: -10)
                        }
                        
                        
                        Button  {
                            listalert.toggle()
                        } label: {
                            HStack{
                                Image(systemName: "gear.circle")
                                Text("Settings")
                            }
                            .font(.system(size: 23))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 65, alignment: .center)
                            .background(Color.gray)
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                        }
                        
                    }
                ).sheet(isPresented: $listalert, content: {
                    NavigationView{
                        List {
                            Button(action: {
                                ShowPortal = true
                            }) {
                                HStack{
                                    Text("Student Health Portal")
                                    Spacer()
                                    Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                                    
                                }.foregroundColor(Color.red)
                                .font(.system(size: 20))}
                            Button(action: {
                                ShowInstruction = true
                            }) {
                                HStack{
                                    Text("Instructions")
                                    Spacer()
                                    Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle")
                                }.font(.system(size: 20))}
                            Button(action: {
                                ShowDetails = true
                            }) {
                                HStack{
                                    Text("About")
                                    Spacer()
                                    Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                                }.font(.system(size: 20))}
                        }
                        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Settings"), displayMode: .inline)
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $ShowPortal, content: {
                        safari()
                    })
                    .sheet(isPresented: $ShowInstruction, content: {
                        Instruction()
                    })
                    .sheet(isPresented: $ShowDetails, content: {
                        Details()
                    })
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $ShowBadge, content: {
                    BadgeScreenView(complianceview: loadImage(), truebadge: truebadge)
                })
                .navigationTitle("Home")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        }
    }
    func saveImage(binding: Binding<Bool>, image: UIImage){
        
        //Need to set @State var truebadge to 'true'
        
        let finalcompliance = image.self.pngData()
        do {
            let furl = try FileManager.default
                .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                .appendingPathComponent("Compliance")
                .appendingPathExtension("png")
            print(furl) // shows url from furl
            fileurl = furl // assigning furl to fileurl allows it to be assigned. But ends up becoming nil
            print(fileurl)  //nil value; doesn't allow the image to load in loadimage() even though assigned to furl
            try finalcompliance?.write(to: furl)
        } catch{
            print("could not create imageFile")
        }
    }
    
    func loadImage() -> UIImage {
        do {
            print("showing the image!")
            if let furl = fileurl {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: furl)
                if let img = UIImage(data: data) {
                    return img
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("error: \(error)") // todo
        }
        return UIImage()
    }
}

struct safari : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<safari>) -> SFSafariViewController{
        
        let controller = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "https://patientportal.bowiestate.edu/login_directory.aspx")!)
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<safari>) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick side note. All property/variable names should begin with a lower case letter. `ShowBadge`, `ShowPortal`, etc... should be `showBadge`, `showPortal`.

Comment: @Fogmeister I know this. I just haven’t changed them them. Do you know the solution to the issue?

Comment: As you return a *dummy* image on failure you could declare `fileurl` as non-optional with a *dummy* default value.